# Even-Mansour Cipher: Efficient algorithms for sampling a random permutation

Tags: permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

My understanding of the Even-Mansour cipher is the following:

- We draw a random permutation $P$ from the set of all permutation $P: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$. This permutation is public.
- We generate two random keys $k_1, k_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$.
- To encrypt a message $m \in \{0,1\}^n$, we compute $E_{k_1, k_2} = P(m \oplus k_1) \oplus k_2$.

What kind of algorithms exists that allow us to efficiently sample (and represent) a permutation $P$ from the set of all permutations from $n$ bit strings to $n$ bit strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even-Mansour is a theoretical model to prove security results. One would need to sample permutations of $n$ bits, say for $n=128,$ since the resulting space of $N=2^n$ objects would be too large to store or manipulate. This is similar to the fact that no one uses a purely random equidistributed and i.i.d. sequence of bits as a keystream in OTP mode in modern cryptography. It is too slow.

However, the following algorithm gives a random permutation on $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}.$ No claim of optimal efficiency is made here.

CODE FOR RANDOM PERMUTATION OF SMALL LIST

**Input:** The list $A=[1,2,\ldots, N]$ of $N=2^n$ items.

**Task:** permute the values in $A$ at random.

Let $S:=\{u: u \in A\}.$ Let $B:=A$

**for each** $i=1,\ldots,N$ **do**

$\quad$ Choose a random integer $j \in S$

$\quad$ Change array $B$ via $B[j]:=A[i]$

$\quad$ Remove $j$ from set $S$

**end for**
This algorithm chooses $N,$ then $N-1$, then $N-2$ etc. objects uniformly and can generate each permutation with equal likelihood, since it makes $N\!$ choices.
**Output:** The list $A$ is now random.

There are more efficient ways to sample random permutations, see for example Jens Gustedt, "Efficient sampling of random permutations", *Journal of Discrete Algorithms*, Vol. 6, Issue 1, 2006. Also take a look at Fisher-Yates shuffle and Knuth Shuffle, google is your friend.

*The algorithm below doesn't quite get there, thanks to @kelalaka for the correction*

**Input:** The list $A=\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$ of $N=2^n$ items.

**Task:** permute the values in $A$ at random.

**for each** $i=0,\ldots,N-1$ **do**

$\quad$ Choose a random integer $j$ with $i<j<N.$

$\quad$ Swap the entries $A[i]$ and $A[j].$

**end for**

**Output:** The list $A$ is now random.

Comment: As we know from the comparison sorting bound, one needs around $n \log n$ swaps to turn back the unsorted array into a sorted one. $N$-swap is not enough to sample all permutations, right?

Comment: Fisher-Yates does result in a uniformly random permutation. Consider the number of possibilities for $A[0]$, then $A[1]$, etc: $N\cdot N-1 \cdot \dots \cdot 1$ = $N!$.